# Not able to create project with phonegap android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am using phonegap for developing android application, But when I am creating a new project it is giving the message

**Project already exists**

But in actual the project is not there . This is my command

> C:\cordova-2.1.0-incubating-src\cordova-2.1.0\incubator-cordova-android\bin>create
>   e:\ com.walkover.musicapp musicapp

Comment: Delete old project . create new workspace and import project their

Comment: @NiravRanpara. But befor importing in eclipse when I am creating the project through command prompt every time it is showing "Project already exists" which ever name I am using.

Comment: Why u create using command line ?  use can create using File menu

Comment: Can we create it directly from eclipse.@nirav ranpara

Comment: I got it. We have to download a plugin for eclipse which you can get from https://sites.google.com/site/mobiledevelopersolutions/home/announce-1/eclipsepluginforphonegapforandroidavailabletoday    thanks @Nirav Ranpara

Comment: Good . Now you can do direct